# How to call Angular component through Java script

Tags: javascript, angular

We want to call a angular component methods publicly through the Java script function.

Comment: What do mean by `call a angular component methods publicly through the Java script function`?

Comment: You mean AngularJS, right?

Comment: Please add some code of what you have tried, the results of it and the expected results.

Answer (score -1):

All methods from an AngularJS Component should be declared in its `$scope`. If that is your case, you should make a querySelector to get the html element that hosts the component you want, with that you can capture the angular scope as below:

```
var element = document.querySelector("<make a query here>");
var angularScope = angular.element(element).scope();
```

You now should be able to invoke any methods (and variables) from the component scope:

```
angularScope.yourMethod();
```

Comment: In our case the element is not present on the page. We want to call the component method from external javascript file. We are using angular v6

Comment: I thought I had understood what you're asking for. Now I'm not sure anymore. If the component isn't in the page, why would you want to call it's methods?